# Python RecordLinkage - Supervised Machine Learning Error

Tags: python, record-linkage

I am building a machine learning model using python Recordlinkage library where model will be trained with pre matched data.

Below is the code snippet:

```
urltrain = "../Training_Set.data"
namestrain = ['TrueMatchID','System','ID','Col1','Col2']

golden_pair = ps.read_csv(urltrain, names=namestrain)

golden_pair = np.asarray(golden_pair).reshape(5000,5)

golden_pair = ps.DataFrame(golden_pair)

indexer = rl.BlockIndex(on='TrueMatchID')
golden_pair_index = indexer.index(golden_pair)

print(indexer)

# Initialize the classifier
logreg = rl.LogisticRegressionClassifier()
# Train the classifier
logreg.learn(golden_pair.all(), golden_pair_index)
```

I am getting error as :

KeyError: "['TrueMatchID'] not in index"

Sample data:

```
TrueMatchID   System     ID  Col1    Col2
12345       2            736     1111.1  1111
12345       1            736     1111.4  1111
54321       1            739     2222.3  2222
54321       2            740     2222    2222.4
```

What seems wrong in the code? I am relatively new to Python so not sure if I am passing some wrong argument.

Answer (score -1):

Here is the annotation of the code you have written -

```
golden_pair = ps.read_csv(urltrain, names=namestrain) # pandas dataframe with column names intact

golden_pair = np.asarray(golden_pair).reshape(5000,5) # converting it to numpy array makes you lose the metadata information of pandas like column names

golden_pair = ps.DataFrame(golden_pair) # here you need to bring back the column names again as it's not present in the numpy array anymore
```

Modify the last line to -

```
golden_pair = ps.DataFrame(golden_pair, columns=namestrain)
```

You can continue with the rest of your code as-is:

```
indexer = rl.BlockIndex(on='TrueMatchID')
golden_pair_index = indexer.index(golden_pair)

print(indexer)

# Initialize the classifier
logreg = rl.LogisticRegressionClassifier()
# Train the classifier
logreg.learn(golden_pair.all(), golden_pair_index)
```

**P.S** I dont understand why you need to reshape and then cast it back to `Dataframe` again. May be you can avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for your help Vivek. I added the reshape since I am getting error:  Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples. Now with the modicfication as u suggested I am still getting this error even with the reshape.Can you please with this error as well.

Comment: @Coder I still don't understand why you need the reshape in the first place. Try doing it without it. Read the csv and then go directly `rl.BlockIndex()`

Comment: Yes Vivek I just did that but getting error : Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 5]. Can you plesae help with this error.